# Pasar datos del Index a una clase MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Buenas, en el fichero Index tengo un Input en el que quiero introducir una cadena de texto y pasarsela a un ActionResult de un controlador, y desde este llamar a un método de otra clase, pero no se muy bien como hacerlo.

Index:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Clase extra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade un argumento a la acción con el mismo nombre del input: `<input id="textCliente" name="textCliente" />` `public ActionResult registrarClientes(String nombre, String textCliente)`. MVC debería realizar el enlace (Binding) de forma automática.

Comment: Parece funcionar, muchas gracias ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En MVC existe lo que se llama Model Binding, entre otras cosas, lo que hace es que por cada elemento de una forma, estos son enviados al método de acción (Action Method). Existen diferentes formas de recibir los elementos de la forma en un Action Method, siendo en este caso, que si tienes un input con un nombre especifico, puedes cachar este valor si esperas un parámetro con el mismo nombre. Entonces en tu caso, lo que necesitas hacer es esperar un campo con el nombre de textCliente

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult registrarClient(string textCliente)
{
   ...
```